# how to allow a user to choose the size on an array

Tags: java, arrays

```js
// Generate array
String input =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("how many numbers would you like to generate?");  

Integer.parseInt(input);

        int size = input;
        int max = 1000; 
        int nums[] = new int[size];

        Random generator = new Random();
        //Write a loop that generates 1000 integers and 
        //store them in the array using generator.nextInt(max)

        generator.nextInt(max); //generating one

        //I need to generate 1000
        //So I need some kind of loop that will generate 1000 numbers. 
        for (int i =0; i<size; i++)
        {
           nums[i] = generator.nextInt(max);
        }
```

My assignment is as follows,

> Write a program that will sort a list of random numbers. The random numbers should be in the range from 0 to 1 000. The user should be able to choose how many numbers they would like to generate.

How would I go about having the user choose the size of an array?
When I try to let the user choose its size it does not work.

I'll leave some simple code I've created in the snippet section.

```
input =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("how large would you like the array?");  

int size = input;

int[] array = new int[size];
```

Comment: write down some code, how'd you do that?

Comment: Look the Scanner class.

Comment: ***Either take input size from user , or go for any Collection : `List` , `Set` etc !***

Comment: divide up your question into smaller problems first. then you can answer your own question.

Comment: What's not working there? seems all right

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the input to a string. `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)` returns a string. Use Integer.parseInt(input) should give you the integer version of the user input. Then you can use this to create the array as you're already doing.

Comment: but when I do that the program has the array underlined in red. when I hover over the error it reads "string cannot be converted to int"

Comment: can you post your exact code for this section? you may not be initializing something properly. Calling `int size = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...));` should work.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(input);` returns the integer. Since you're not setting it equal to anything, input is still the string value. You need to grab the result of calling parseInt by combining these two lines `Integer.parseInt(input);` and `int size = input;` into `int size = Integer.parseInt(input);`